# partial http auth on multidomain multi store setup

Tags: .htaccess, http-authentication

i've got two domains leading to the same filebase (shop) on a multi-store setup. let's say i've got those URLs:

www.first-shop.xyz

www.second-shop.xyz

now i need to password-protect second-shop.xyz without affecting the other one. is there a possibility to set conditional auth in htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to manage this in .htaccess-File.

But it can be done with [PHP-HTTP-Auth](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) .

So it is possible to check the `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` against the desired domain and then return header 401 if `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']` not match the credentials.

If those two auth vars stay empty after filling out the prompt you will need a .htaccess rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authori
zation}]
```

to get the auth vars in environment variables and assign them to the above vars like that:

```
list($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'], $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) = explode(':' , base64_decode(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'], 6)));
```